# Retrieve title of a Node within Firebase RealTime Database Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the first header within a specific node. I have attached an example of my JSON tree below. There will be multiple nodes and the data within each is static.

I have a dropdown that contains the headers at a top-level "First Tree" and "Second Tree". I have another dropdown that would need to display the header directly under the option selected by the user (there would be multiple years).

How is it possible to get the "year" value from the tree? I can get all the data under a child by typing the path but cannot grab the header directly after the top-level node.

[image]

```
func dataTest() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref?.child("\(selectedStringFromDropdown)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print(snapshot.children)
            } else {
                print("No snapshot")
                return
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: isn't it static key `year` ?

Comment: it would be 2018/19/20. "Year" would not be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
print(snapshot.children)
let res = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
let arr = Array(res.keys)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like it's working correctly, iIadded two-year values and it printed out ["2020", "2019"] as expected. However, I need to add these values within a [String]() array so it can be used with the iOSdropdown framework from cocoapods.

As res is a dict, how can I can a grab the values and append to an empty string array that is declared upon loading? thanks!